# GDrive API Upload files javascript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

Segui todos os passos e algumas outras perguntas que encontrei aqui no stack, e usando o seguinte código posso upar um arquivo para o Google Drive:

```
var importFiles = $('#files')[0].files;

const boundary = '--pd_upload';
const delimiter = "\r\n"+boundary+"\r\n";
const close_delim = "\r\n"+boundary+"--";

var metadata = {
                'name': importFiles[0]["name"],
                'mimeType': importFiles[0]["type"],
                'parents':['parent-id']
            };

var multipartRequestBody =
                    delimiter+ 
                        'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n'+
                        JSON.stringify(metadata)+"\r\n"+
                    delimiter+"\r\n"+ 
                        'Content-Type: '+importFiles[0]["type"]+"\r\n\r\n"+
                        importFiles[0]+
                    close_delim;    

gapi.client.request({
                    'path': '/upload/drive/v3/files',
                    'method': 'POST',
                    'params': {
                            'uploadType': 'multipart'
                    },
                    'headers': {
                                'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+gapi.client.getToken()["access_token"],
                                'Content-Type': 'multipart/related; boundary="pd_upload"'
                    },
                    'body': multipartRequestBody

})
```

Parece que tudo funciona normal, o Google cria o arquivo, na pasta designada, com o nome do mesmo, porém não é possível visualizar o arquivo, como se o mesmo não tivesse sido enviado. O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive o mesmo problema, no entanto, estou usando RestSharp para as requisições HTTP.

O meu problema é que eu estava passando uma imagem no body em base64, mas eu deveria passar essa imagem em binário.

Provavelmente você está passando o arquivo no formato errado. Você pode tentar usar o [file.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) para criar o arquivo no formato correto antes de enviar.

Não sei se ajuda, mas esse é o meu código:

```
[HttpPost]
public string PostImage(){
    var restclient = new RestClient(BaseUrl);
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media") {Method = Method.POST};

    string imageBase64 = "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";

    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageBase64);

   request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
   request.AddHeader("Content-Length", "5951");
   request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Authenticantion());
   request.AddParameter("application/json", bytes, ParameterType.RequestBody);

   var tResponse = restclient.Execute(request);
   var responseJson = tResponse.Content;

   return responseJson;
}
```

Comment: Também tem essa outra pergunta que o cara falou um caso parecido https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352682/uploaded-file-does-not-show-when-using-google-drive-api